# Who was the American settler Tolman of Kamchatka?

Tags: kamchatka, settlement, individuals

In *To the Pacific and Arctic with Beechey: The Journal of Lieutenant George Peard of HMS Blossom, 1825–1828*, Peard mentions visiting "Mr. Tolman an American Settler" in Avatcha, Kamchatka, "7 or 8 miles from Petropaulowski towards the bottom of the bay".

I've not found anything else on this fellow. Who was he and what was he up to in Kamchatka?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

William "Василий" Tolman was a New Englander born in 1793. According to the book "Тайны камчатских имен", he arrived in Petropavlovsk, Kamchatka in 1813.

A story about one of his daughters, long settled in the USA, getting in touch with her brothers was published in several American newspapers in the 1890s. According to [this story](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=MG18930408.2.55&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN--------1), her father had been working on a whaling ship (I would love to know which one). The ship stopped in Kamchatka for repairs, which he made successfully. He stayed and served as a translator. His decision to stay may be linked to his marriage to a local woman named Daria Egorovna Kikenova. They have [loads of descendants](https://pandia.ru/text/80/297/33755.php) living today. ["Вопросы истории Камчатки"](http://www.knigakamchatka.ru/pdf/voprosy-istorii-kamchatki-9.pdf) says that some of them were involved in defending Petropavlovsk during the siege of 1854.

Comment: @JohnDee sure, you got it.