# Which ship took Tolman to Kamchatka?

Tags: 19th-century, age-of-sail, immigration, ships, kamchatka

[William Tolman](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/48286/who-was-the-american-settler-tolman-of-kamchatka) was reportedly a mechanic from New England who got to Petropavlovsk on a whaling ship in 1813. Somehow he stayed behind and lived his whole long life in Kamchatka.

None of the sources I found reading about Tolman named the ship. I found nothing useful in the American Offshore Whaling Voyages Database. The author of a paper called "Yankee Whalers in Siberia" (1946) was also ignorant of this voyage. Likely it was not a whaler after all. The article [Whaling in the Sea of Okhotsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whaling_in_the_Sea_of_Okhotsk) says whaling operations in the nearby Sea of Okhotsk didn't begin until the 1830s; [Whaling in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whaling_in_the_United_States) says that American whalers didn't reach Hawaii until 1820, and it's hard to imagine them getting to Kamchatka first. Worth noting, Peter Dobell sent two trade ships to Kamchatka from Canton in 1812.

What was the ship on which Tolman arrived?